# ExecutorService - fill up progress bar in JavaFX with the number of finished tasks

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, executorservice

I have a code which sends files concurrently via ExecutorService. However, I want to have a progress bar in JavaFX, which would fill up with the number of files sent.

How would I achieve so?

I'm creating tasks via `List<Callable<String>> clientTasks = new ArrayList<>();`, and lauching them via `es.invokeAll(clientTasks);`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along the following lines:

```
IntegerProperty completed = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
List<Callable<String>> wrappedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (Callable<String> task : clientTasks) {
    wrappedTasks.add(() -> {
        String result = task.call();
        Platform.runLater(() -> completed.set(completed.get()+1));
        return result ;
    });
}
completed.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    progressBar.setProgress(1.0 * newValue.intValue() / clientTasks.size()));
es.invokeAll(wrappedTasks);
```

Comment: Thanks. In meanwhile I tried to create my own solution. I'm sending progress bar as an argument to clientTask class, and incrementing it each time it finish. Is my solution also correct?

Comment: There should not be `<>` after `new SimpleIntegerProperty`.

Comment: @Peter It's probably not a great design for the task class to know details of the UI. For example, suppose you decided later you wanted to update a label instead of a progress bar; you'd have to modify the task class. You've created too much dependency in your code.

Comment: @James_D You are probably right, I will change it. Do you think it might create some problems at the execution level? There are multiple clientTasks running at the same time. Do I need to synchronize it somehow?

Comment: @Peter No, because you have to update the progress bar on the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater()`. So all access to the count of completed tasks is single-threaded.

Comment: @James_D Thanks. One last question, I'm getting an error The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Number in your code. How to fix it?